# Stuck in "Updates and other software" page when trying to boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb

I am a windows user. Trying to move to Ubuntu. I have a bootable USB from where trying to install Ubuntu 20.04. but when I am going to "Updates and other software" pages of the installation process, I am getting stuck.

I read others thread like this but seems the environment of mine is not same as them. I read to unmount windows boot partition, but I can't unmount C drive in windows. That's why that did not worked for me. But I really want to switch to Ubuntu. Please help me.

I want to delete windows fully and then will give ubuntu.

I am adding two pictures. One when the problem occured, another is the situation when I made the usb bootable.

[image]

This is before making USB bootable.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you click "Continue" ?

Comment: "Continue" isn't clickable. It is grey in color, btw. @SorenA

Comment: Is your Windows system encrypted with Bitlocker, did you had any failed Ubuntu installations before? Have you tried unmounting the Windows partition?

Comment: no encryption... I am have been trying for several hours, every time getting failure Ubuntu installation on same page(Updates and other software)... I have tried unmounting windows, but C drive is not permitted to do this.  @kortewegdevries

Comment: What do you mean by "C drive is not permitted to do this"? Boot into a live environment, type `lsblk` or `sudo fdisk -l`, identify your `C:` drive type `sudo umount /dev/sdaX` and run the installer again from the desktop. In case it's busy trying using `umount -l` or `-f`

Comment: I have not installed ubuntu yet. The command you are giving is to run from ubuntu, right? I have only one os now, that is windows. And my os is installed in C drive. which is not permitted to unmount. @kortewegdevries

Comment: Insert the USB you created, boot it>Try Ubuntu>Live session opens up,Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal.

Comment: Ok got it. But when I click on try Ubuntu..  it just got stuck.. nothing happens.

Comment: Start Windows then choose Shut Down while holding down the SHIFT key to make sure Windows closes completely. Then try adding Ubuntu alongside Windows.

Comment: thanks all... I installed 18.04 ... it worked without any problem. And removed windows completely.